# Can multiple divs with different Ids use one JavaScript function to control them separately?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work out how to make a single JavaScript function control multiple `divs`.

I have multiple `divs` with different `ids` and I wrote identical JavaScript functions for each of them separately. However, the functions either don't work or only one of them does.

I think that most likely they are stopping each other from working and I am wondering if there is a way to use a single JavaScript function but keeping the unique `ids` on the `divs`.

Here is a very simple example of what I'm working with:

Note: the script is supposed to close a window if a user clicks anywhere outside a "container" window. At the moment, only clicking on the last yellow container

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('window-one');

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var modal = document.getElementById('window-two');

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var modal = document.getElementById('window-three');

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 2px black;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="window-one" class="container-one">1</div>
<div id="window-two" class="container-two">2</div>
<div id="window-three" class="container-three">3</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you declare the same variable 3 times with 3 different values. Your variable is declared globally. So it will be overwritten every time.

Also, the solution would be to add a common property to all modals ( eg. a className ) . Select them all. See which one is clicked and do stuff with it.

See below a simplistic example

```js
const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal')

const doStuffWithModal = (modal) => modal.style.display = 'none'

modals.forEach(modal => modal.addEventListener('click', () => doStuffWithModal(modal)))
```

```css
.modal {
width: 100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
margin: 20px
}

.modal.container-two {
  background:blue
}
.modal.container-three {
    background: green
}
```

```html
<div id="window-one" class="container-one modal"></div>
<div id="window-two" class="container-two modal "></div>
<div id="window-three" class="container-three modal" ></div>
```